# Calling functions which take their arguments interactively

Tags: functions, button

Lets say I have a file named `test.m` containing some functions.

```
test[arg1_, arg2_] := (
  Print[arg1];
  Print[arg2];
)
test3[arg1_, arg2_] := (
  Print[arg1];
  Print[arg2];
)
```

What would be a good way to generate a list of butons that would allow you to invoke the functions easily?  For example.

[image]

The tricky part here (and is mainly why I am asking this question) is calling the functions, which will have several different argument types?  I had thought about using an `InputField` with a `MessageDialog`, but I would bet there is better way to incorporate *Mathematica*'s features.

```
ClearAll[loadFile];
loadFile[path_String?FileExistsQ] := DeleteCases[ToExpression[
    FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[path]]
    , InputForm, HoldComplete], Null];
x = ReleaseHold[
   loadFile["test.m"] /.
    HoldPattern[sym_[args__] := eval_] :>
     Button[sym, eval]
   ];
x[[0]] = List;
x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code allows you to click the button which will allow you call the function.  **(functionality still buggy, 2 options 1) add functions to Global namespace 2) figure out some way to allow you to call the functions )**.

```
ClearAll[loadFile];
loadFile[path_String?FileExistsQ] := 
  DeleteCases[
   ToExpression[FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[path]], InputForm, 
    HoldComplete], Null];

Cases[
 loadFile["test.m"] /. 
    HoldPattern[sym_[args___] := eval_] :> 
     Button[Defer[sym], CellPrint[Cell[
         BoxData@ToBoxes[Defer[sym[args]]]
         , "Input", Evaluatable -> True, 
         CellEvaluationFunction -> Function[ToExpression[#];], 
         ShowStringCharacters -> True
         ]];
      ] /.
   HoldPattern[Pattern][a__, _[x___]] :> Placeholder[a _ x] /. 
  List :> CompoundExpression,
 Button[___]
 ]
```

[image]